# I want to make a timer that stops at a specific time in java

Tags: java, if-statement, timer

So I tried to make a timer that will stop at specific time i put in the if statement, though it didn't work. Is there a way I can do this that will work?

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class time {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        do {
            Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss");
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(strDate);
            if (strDate == "06 03:22:30") {
                System.out.println("timer done");
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Also, check out [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: You cannot compare strings using the == operator in java. Use equals() instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the condition matches , please add the break statement . Else it will print and continue processing and it will end up in an infinite loop .Also add compare the string equality using .equals() method and not ==(that is reference comparison)

```
public class time {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        do {
            Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss");
            String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println(strDate);
            if (strDate.equals("06 03:22:30")) {
                System.out.println("timer done");
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, but that doesn't solve my original problem.

Comment: I have updated the code . Please check now , it should work.